# How to Dynamically Set Enviroment Variables in Apache2

Tags: php, apache2

On a test server, we use wildcards in the `ServerAlias` for dynamically generated sub domains.

Issue is i need to set a required custom environment called `APP_HOME` to be identical to the `document_root`.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName testserver.com
    ServerAlias *.testserver.com
    VirtualDocumentRoot = /var/www/branch/%1/
    SetEnv APP_HOME = /var/www/branch/%1/
</VirtualHost>
```

The expected result is for `APP_HOME` and `DOCUMENT_ROOT` to be the same, but currently

```
DOCUMENT_ROOT becomes /var/www/branch/testbranch/
```

and

```
APP_HOME becomes /var/www/branch/%1/
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20671140/using-apache-config-and-htaccess-to-dynamically-set-config-vars-for-dev-and-prod) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568191/how-to-get-system-environment-variables-into-php-while-running-cli-apache2hand#_=_) may help

Comment: Thanls but neither help as neither handle dynamic content in the SetEnv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was never really resolved.

In the end we analysed the codebase and found that the custom enviroment variable was not needed and blanket replaced it with DOCUMENT_ROOT

One caveat was needing to ensure DOCUMENT_ROOT was set / passed in for cronjobs or cli operations.